# Guardar consulta en variable y validar si ya existe registro en un Procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo este procedimiento en el que genero un cursor con los registros de una tabla temporal de localidades, donde se agregan localidades con su respectiva acción **A(agregar), B(borrar) y M(modificar)**, hago un *loop* el cual recorre el cursor tomando en cuenta la acción especificada en dicha tabla, lo cual hace correctamente en los *case*, pero he querido que en la acción A(agregar) que es un *insert*, valide primero si ese registro ya existe y si es así lo omita.

**Este es mi intento:**

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE PA_LOCS IS
    /*SE CREA CURSOR, CADA UNO ALMACENA LOS REGISTROS SEGUN LA ACCION DE LA TABLA TMP_CATLOCALIDADES*/
    CURSOR C_ACC_LOCS IS SELECT * FROM CATA.TMP_LOCALIDADES WHERE ACCION IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ACCION;/*VERIFICA QUE EL CAMPO ACCION NO ESTE VACIO*/
    
    /*SECCION DE DECLARACION DE VARIABLES PARA CONTADOR DEL LOPP*/ 
    v_regRepeat      VARCHAR2(50);
    v_add            number := 0;
    v_del            number := 0;
    v_upd            number := 0;
    v_other          number := 0;
    v_repeat         number := 0;

BEGIN
     FOR a in C_ACC_LOCS loop
       CASE a.ACCION WHEN 'A' THEN
       /*CONSULTA PARA VERIFICAR ID REPETIDO DE LOCALIDAD, EL RESULTADO SE GUARDA EN V_REGREPEAT*/
         SELECT LOCPLAN_ID INTO v_regRepeat FROM CATA.C_LOCALIDADES WHERE LOCPLAN_ID = a.LOCPLAN_ID;
         /*SI LA VARIABLE ESTA VACIA INSERTAMOS EL REGISTRO*/
            IF v_regRepeat = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO C_LOCALIDADES (LOCPLAN_ID, ESTADO_ID, MUNICIPIO_ID, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, LOCALIDAD_ID, CLAVEOFI, SITUACION_ID, COORDENADA_X,
                COORDENADA_Y, LATITUD, LONGITUD) VALUES (a.LOCPLAN_ID, a.ESTADO_ID, a.MUNICIPIO_ID, a.LOCALIDAD, a.NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, a.LOCALIDAD_ID, a.CLAVEOFI, a.SITUACION_ID, a.COORDENADA_X,
                a.COORDENADA_Y, a.LATITUD, a.LONGITUD);
            ELSE 
         v_repeat:=v_repeat+1; 
            END IF;
        v_add:=v_add+1;
       WHEN 'B' THEN
            UPDATE C_LOCALIDADES SET SITUACION_ID = 0 WHERE LOCPLAN_ID = a.LOCPLAN_ID;
          v_del:=v_del+1;
       WHEN 'M' THEN
            UPDATE C_LOCALIDADES SET NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD = a.NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, SITUACION_ID = a.SITUACION_ID,
            COORDENADA_X = a.COORDENADA_X, COORDENADA_Y = a.COORDENADA_Y, LATITUD = a.LATITUD, LONGITUD = a.LONGITUD
            WHERE LOCPLAN_ID = a.LOCPLAN_ID;
          v_upd:=v_upd+1;
       ELSE
          v_other:=v_other+1;
       END CASE;
    end loop;
     /*INSERT INTO B_CATLOCALIDADES (LOCPLAN_ID, ESTADO_ID, MUNICIPIO_ID, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, LOCALIDAD_ID, CLAVEOFI, SITUACION_ID, COORDENADA_X,
            COORDENADA_Y, LATITUD, LONGITUD, ACCION, FECHA, CALENDARIO) VALUES (a.LOCPLAN_ID, a.ESTADO_ID, a.MUNICIPIO_ID, a.LOCALIDAD, a.NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, a.LOCALIDAD_ID, a.CLAVEOFI, a.SITUACION_ID, a.COORDENADA_X,
            a.COORDENADA_Y, a.LATITUD, a.LONGITUD, a.ACCION, sysdate, a.CALENDARIO);*/
   
    COMMIT;
     
     /*CUERPO DEL LOG DEL PROCEDIMIENTO*/
    dbms_output.put_line('LAS ACCIONES PARA LA TABLA CAT_LOCALIDADES SON:'||chr(10)
                        ||'REGISTROS AGREGADOS - ' || v_add||chr(10)
                        ||'REGISTROS REPETIDOS - ' || v_repeat||chr(10)
                        ||'REGISTROS ELIMINADOS - ' || v_del||chr(10)
                        ||'REGISTROS MODIFICADOS - ' || v_upd||chr(10)
                        ||'OTROS - ' || v_other);
END;
```

Comment: puedes crear un triger que valide si existe no lo cree...!

Comment: Ese es el detalle, no se como hacerlo o en que parte del procedimiento iría, por eso intente hacerlo de esta forma, pero en principio me sale error al tratar de guardar el **select** del case A en una variable, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar un select  para validar el registro a insertar

IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C_LOCALIDADES WHERE LOCPLAN_ID=a.LOCPLAN_ID, ESTADO_ID, MUNICIPIO_ID, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, LOCALIDAD_ID, CLAVEOFI, SITUACION_ID, COORDENADA_X,
COORDENADA_Y, LATITUD, LONGITUD)=0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO C_LOCALIDADES (LOCPLAN_ID, ESTADO_ID, MUNICIPIO_ID, LOCALIDAD, NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, LOCALIDAD_ID, CLAVEOFI, SITUACION_ID, COORDENADA_X,
COORDENADA_Y, LATITUD, LONGITUD)
VALUES (a.LOCPLAN_ID, a.ESTADO_ID, a.MUNICIPIO_ID, a.LOCALIDAD, a.NOMBRE_LOCALIDAD, a.LOCALIDAD_ID, a.CLAVEOFI, a.SITUACION_ID, a.COORDENADA_X,
a.COORDENADA_Y, a.LATITUD, a.LONGITUD);
END

Comment: No me funciono amigo, me sale error, ya que la estructura es un procedimiento almacenado.